# How to not follow redirects with Darts http-package? request.followRedirects = false is set

Tags: flutter, dart, http, http-redirect, dart-http

I'm trying to implement a small http wrapper with Flutter and Dart as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HttpWrapper {
  http.Client httpClient = http.Client();

  Future<http.StreamedResponse> backendHttpRequest(
      String method, String endpoint) async {
    String backendUrlBase = const String.fromEnvironment("backend_url_base");

    var uri = Uri.parse(backendUrlBase + endpoint);
    http.Request request = http.Request(method, uri);
    request.followRedirects = false;

    var response = await httpClient.send(request);

    if (response.isRedirect) {
      debugPrint("Redirecting...");
      // handle redirect
      return response;
    } else {
      return response;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to handle redirects separately, since the server may redirect me to an endpoint which does not accept XMLHttpRequests, which runs me into CORS issues then. This wouldn't be a problem if I could just handle the redirect response on my own, as I tried with handling `response.statusCode == 302` - **my problem is that `request.followRedirect = false` does not seem to have an effect at all.** The client just follows the redirects, no matter what I set followRedirects.

How can I solve this, that my request does not follow redirects?

Thank you for your help!

Edit 1: *Changed `response.statusCode == 302` to `response.isRedirect`*

Edit 2:
**How I produce the problem:**

I have set up an example server in express as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
const logger = require('morgan');
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cors()) 

// Without middleware
app.get('/endpointwhichredirects', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Redirecting...");
    res.redirect('/user');
});
 
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
    res.send("This is the user-page");
});
 
app.listen(PORT, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("Server listening on PORT", PORT);
});
```

I use my http-wrapper in Dart as follows:

```
HttpWrapper httpWp = HttpWrapper();
res = httpWp.backendHttpRequest('Get', '/endpointwhichredirects');
```

My server logs the following when this Dart-code gets executed:

```
> GET /endpointwhichredirects 302 3.051 ms - 27
> GET /user 304 2.986 ms - -
```

The debug print "Redirecting..." never gets calles. If I set a breakpoint for both returns of `response` only the one in the else branch gets caught, never the one handling the redirect.

Comment: FWIW, setting `request.followRedirects = false` works for  me when I try it with a simple `GET` request to a redirecting URL.  Are you sure that your server is reporting a status code of 302 (and not 301, 307, or 308)?  Have you tried it with hard-coded URLs?  Is it possible to provide a complete example that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @jamesdlin - thanks for your suggestions - I added above an example on how I produce the problem in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the explanation in the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/browser_client/BrowserClient-class.html):

> A dart:html-based HTTP client that runs in the browser and is backed by
> XMLHttpRequests. This client inherits some of the limitations of XMLHttpRequest. **It ignores** the BaseRequest.contentLength, BaseRequest.persistentConnection, **BaseRequest.followRedirects**, and BaseRequest.maxRedirects fields. It is also unable to stream requests or responses; a request will only be sent and a response will only be returned once all the data is available.

Reason seems to be that with XMLHttpRequest redirects are transparent followed by the browser.